# mostrar o valor dos inputs filhos de divs js

Tags: javascript, for, while

preciso que o for/while mostre na tela a string colocada no input do primeiro div na primeira vez que o laço for executado e na segunda vez mostre na tela a string colocada no input do segundo div e assim sucessivamente.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="cki11" class="ind">
 <input class="in" id="in1" placeholder="Nome do indicado">
</div>
<div id="cki12" class="ind">
 <input class="in" id="in1" placeholder="Nome do indicado">
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var i = 1;
    var x = 2;
    var a = 5;
    var e = 5;
    
    while(i <= x){
     a = "cki1" + i.toString(); // armazena a string correspondente ao id da div que sera chamada
        e = document.getElementById(a).children[0].value; // pega o valor do input com base no div pai
        document.write(e+"<br>");// exibe o valor do input 
        i++;
    }
    
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Postei uma resposta, se tiver dificuldade de entender explico como funciona;

Comment: Lucas repara que `id="in1"` vai gerar IDs repetidos na página, isso é HTML inválido, tens de ter IDs únicos.

Comment: Nao tinha reparado... Valeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque não só isto?

```js
function myFunction() {
    var inputArray =  document.querySelectorAll(".ind input");
    for(let i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++){
      document.write(inputArray[i].value + '<br>');
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="cki11" class="ind">
 <input class="in" id="in1" placeholder="Nome do indicado">
</div>
<div id="cki12" class="ind">
 <input class="in" id="in1" placeholder="Nome do indicado">
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Marconi... Deu certo!!